# Analyzing animal behavioural data in R Studio (GLMM) and struggling to understand how to set up the model

Tags: r, mixed-model, model-selection, glmm, count-data

I'm trying to determine whether there was any differences in behaviour (count data, frequency per 30 minute observations, categorized into 5 categories [e.g., affiliative, agonistic, etc.]) of a captive troop of baboons between lockdown (no visitors) and out of lockdown (varying numbers of visitors). I also have environmental variables data (e.g., weather, temperature, wind speed, etc.) and management variables (e.g., group size present, time since last feed, etc.).

I don't know if I have too many random effects for one generalized linear mixed model (GLMM) or if that's even the correct test to do. I've been working with the following code:

```
Affiliative <- glmer(Affiliative/Total ~ Feed.Lag + Weather + Temperature + Group.Size + (1 | Open), data = baboon, family = binomial, na.action = na.omit, weight = Total)
```

I've set `Weather` and `Open` (i.e., lockdown vs. no lockdown) to `as.factor()` variables, as they are non-numeric and just variables given an arbitrary number for my analysis. The rest of the variables I've left alone as they are numeric.

I thought I'd use each behavioural category one at a time to see which variable, if any, changed behaviour, but I'm unsure if I've set up the code up correctly. It runs and I get significant results back, but my understanding of which variables are fixed/random and where they fit in the code isn't great.

Any help really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you saying `Open` is a factor with 2 levels (lockdown/no lockdown) ? Why do you think this should be a random effect ? Why do you say " don't know if I have too many random effects " ?

Comment: Yes Open is a factor with 2 levels, lockdown (no visitors) / no lockdown (visitors).  In terms of the code, I'm unsure if there are too many variables within it, I know that once it's running properly I can remove those that aren't significant but am unsure if there's too much involved

Answer (score 2):

Your model:

```
Affiliative <- glmer(Affiliative/Total ~ Feed.Lag + Weather + Temperature + Group.Size + (1 | Open), data = baboon, family = binomial, na.action = na.omit, weight = Total)
```

does not make sense.

Since `Open` is a factor with 2 levels you cannot use it as a grouping variable for random intercepts. When you fit random intercepts you are telling the software that this is a normally distributed variable and you are asking it to estimate the variance of it. With only 2 observations, this is not sensible. It should be a fixed effect.

From the information given I don't see any reason to fit a mixed effects model. A GLM (either poisson or binomial) would be more appropriate.

In the comments you say:

> I know that once it's running properly I can remove those that aren't significant

Please do not do this. Variables should be included in a model because the underlying theory dictates so, not because a p value is below some arbitrary value. Variables should be included when they are competing exposures or potential confounders. If any variable is a mediator it should be omitted.